# selenium, python clicking button (Edited for another issue)

Tags: python, selenium

I solved the problem I mentioned below. This time I'm trying a different mp3 converter site (https://h2converter.com/tr/) with my script because in the previous site, the ad pop-ups arise. However, the web driver can't find the button this time and the program stops due to the time out exception. In order for my script to find the button "precisely", I used xpath. The new version of my code is as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://h2converter.com/tr/")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("video")
element.send_keys("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZobdNXT0Za0", Keys.ENTER)

downloadElem=WebDriverWait(driver, 
60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id=download']")))
downloadElem.click()
```

> I'm new to Selenium. I'm coding a script that will automatize the download process of converted MP3's. With driver.find_element_by_css_selector, the script gives NoSuchElementException error. I read the other posts that mention the same problem;however, they didn't help me. How can I solve it? My code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.onlinevideoconverter.com/mp3-converter")

element = driver.find_element_by_name("texturl")
element.send_keys("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZobdNXT0Za0", Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("download-button").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here: (1) you specify the button the wrong way; and (2) you do not let the browser wait until the button is available.

## Specifying the button

Here `download-button` is the **`class="download-button"`**. A **CSS selector prefixes class specifications with a dot `.`**, so you should write:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".start-button").click()
#                                    ^
```

Alternatively, you can use [**`find_element_by_class_name(..)`**](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-class-name):

```
# No dot prefix
driver.find_element_by_class_name("start-button").click()
```

## Waiting until processing is done

Since it can take a few seconds, we can not immediately find the button. It can take considerable time. We thus will have wait. You can let a program with with `time.sleep(..)`. We thus can rewrite it to:

```
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.onlinevideoconverter.com/mp3-converter")

element = driver.find_element_by_name("texturl")
element.send_keys("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZobdNXT0Za0", Keys.ENTER)

sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("download-button").click()
```

## Polling frequently

The above is a bit time consuming: we waint five seconds in the hope that the button pops up. If the process finishes earlier, then we wait for nothing. If on the other hand processing still takes place, we might run again into an error. We can change the script, and start "polling" until the button shows up:

```
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.onlinevideoconverter.com/mp3-converter")

element = driver.find_element_by_name("texturl")
element.send_keys("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZobdNXT0Za0", Keys.ENTER)

while True:
    sleep(0.5)
    try:
        button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("download-button")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    else:
        button.click()
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly ! However, it still throws the same error:

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":".download-button"}

Comment: @SüleymanYaman: in the second one, the dot prefix is *not* used.

Comment: Both of them threw the error again. In the source code of the page, I see "style class". May it be related to this ?

Comment: @SüleymanYaman: I think I see the problem: it takes time to process it, you need to let the program sleep before the `download-button` shows up.

Comment: the question mentioned nothing about the button not appearing on page load.  However, If the OP actually did need waits, I *definitely* wouldn't recommend static sleeps.  Also the polling example just re-implements the mechanism of Explicit Waits... no need to roll your own.  Please wait properly using Explicit Waits and Expected Conditions (both are part of webdriver).

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for download button to visible (which takes time in your case) 
there are two options:
1. Set sleep manually:

```
time.sleep(max_seconds_wait)
```

2. wait for download button visible dynamically

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


try:
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'downloadq')))
except:
      .....
```

Comment: don't use static sleeps.  the second suggestion is the way to do it.